# Appsmith - embedded MangoDB connection error Appsmith container image update

Tags: appsmith

I recently pull a recent image of Appsmith and from that moment I can't get it running.
The container logs shows: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

I don't even know which exact version I was running before (between v1.9.37 & 42).. I tried to modify docker.env file by changing Mango_URI params without success. Note that the mangoDb is the embedded one, no external.

I tried also to delete the docker.env & certificate/conf files and let the Appsmith rebuild them. I tried also to pull old images from v1.9.37.. but still no success.

Always the same MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED!

Then I have in // setup a new container with last Appsmith image and the app is running without issue. But All my work form 1st container is inaccessible. Lost?

I think it is about mangoDb user/password issue, because on the docker.env params:

```
APPSMITH_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://appsmith:aSgGaIj1jtz3U@localhost:27017/appsmith
APPSMITH_MONGODB_USER=appsmith
APPSMITH_MONGODB_PASSWORD=aSgGaIj1jtz3U
APPSMITH_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/api/v1
```

Password is changing when you pull a new image..? I noticed that I have different pwd each time I get another image.

Is there a way to recover this connection? Or how can I solve this if this is possible?
I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

PS: I'm newby with container handling and appsmith app.

Regards,